# Scalaz: how to apply a function to the success of a ValidationNel?

Tags: scala, scalaz

this is my code `x :->GetUsersByPhone` where `x: scalaz.ValidationNel[ValidationError, Seq[PhoneNumberWithIdentifier]]`.

`GetusersByPhone` is simply a case class that wraps the `Seq[PhoneNumberWithIdentifier]`

My problem is with the `:->` operator that I think is correct but it raises this error:

```
[error] /home/simone/radicalbit/mpay-user/play/src/main/scala/com/next/mpay/users/validators/users/GetUsersByPhoneValidation.scala:31: value :-> is not a member of scalaz.ValidationNel[com.next.mpay.users.validators.ValidationError,Seq[com.next.mpay.users.persistence.PhoneNumberWithIdentifier]]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value :->'?
[error]           .:->(GetUsersByPhone)
[error]            ^
```

How can I fix that? Do I need to import something else besides `scalaz._` and `scalaz.Scalaz._`?

Comment: Have you tried `GetUsersByPhone.apply`?

Comment: yep but it returns the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `map` should work, because `Validation` is right-biased:

```
x.map(GetUsersByPhone)
```

---

Method `:->` comes from a `Bifunctor` instance.

But although `ValidationNel[A, B]` is just a type alias for `Validation[NonEmptyList[A], B]`, and there is a `Bifunctor` instance for `Validation`, the compiler still can't find a `Bifunctor` instance for `ValidationNel`.

Coercing `ValidationNel` to the respective `Validation` would also work though:

```
(x: Validation[NonEmptyList[ValidationError], Seq[PhoneNumberWithIdentifier]])
  .:->(GetUsersByPhone)
```